# Hook_views_query_alter: adding condition with entity reference value

Tags: views, hooks

I need to filter a table result based the current user.

I added this condition in my hook_views_query_alter

```
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  global $user;
  if ($view->name == 'preventivi' && $view->current_display == 'page_3') 
  {
    // $view->query->add_where(1, $user->uid, 33, '=');
    $view->query->add_where(1, "field_data_field_installatori_reference.field_installatori_reference_target_id", $user->uid, '!=');

    // dpm($view);
    //dpm($query);
  }
}
```

but I can't find the correct value of `target_id` to insert in the condition.
Any suggestion?

Comment: What version of drupal

Answer (score 0):

This comment save my life!
https://api.drupal.org/comment/49458#comment-49458

> Be careful to add the table, even if You added the field in the view
>   UI :

I added

```
$view->query->add_table("field_data_field_installatori_reference");
```

and then I could access to my field:

```
$view->query->add_where(1, "field_data_field_installatori_reference.field_installatori_reference_target_id", $user->uid, '!=');
```